# Ruby Regex MatchData Object Captures Method Behaving Oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

So if you take a Ruby 2.1.2 regex object

```
reg = /(?!gemspec)gem.*/
```

and call match on a line like the following:

```
"gem 'wirble', :group => :development"
```

You get the following MatchData object:

```
 #<MatchData "gem 'wirble', :group => :development">
```

If you call

```
 reg.match("gem 'wirble', :group => :development").to_a
 => ["gem 'wirble', :group => :development"]
```

But if you call

```
reg.match("gem 'wirble', :group => :development").captures
 => []
```

The documentation for MatchData (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) states that the #captures method should return the same value as the #to_a method on the match object returned from that Regex call. In this instance it doesn't appear that way. Why the discrepancy? Is this a bug?

The post is pretty terse, let me know if you need any other explanation!

Comment: Actually, that doc says it's equivalent to `to_a[1..-1]`.  It includes only the contents of the capturing groups, not the whole match.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference then. Shouldn't that range return the whole array from the second element on? What is the capturing group vs the match?

Comment: Capturing groups allow you extract substrings from within the match.  `#captures` returns only those, while `#to_a` also includes the whole match.  The [`#to_a` doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html#method-i-to_a) shows it more clearly.

Comment: Bugs in Ruby do surface from time-to-time, but most are caught quickly and dealt with by the extermination team. I've encountered much puzzling behaviour in Ruby code, but it's never been due to a bug or, for that matter, a hardware error.

Comment: I guess most of the time I encounter problems it is the same. My most frustrating thing to deal with for any language is just documentation, which was the problem here as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. It actually works properly. `#captures` only returns **captured** contents which mean the contents that are matched for groups within round brackets `()`. If you modify your regex to `/(?!gemspec)gem(.*)/` (notice the `(.*)` part), `reg.match("gem 'wirble', :group => :development").captures` will return `[" 'wirble', :group => :development"]`.